# What Report Events happen after the report is made?

Tags: ms-access

I have a template of a Report.  When it's opened by the Navigation Form, I wish to alter it as it opens.

Problem is the report doesn't exist yet.  What event can I put my code into that happens after it's constructed but before user interaction?

Comment: Probably in the `Format` event. What is it that you need to alter? You look at this here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/order-of-events-for-database-objects-e76fbbfe-6180-4a52-8787-ce86553682f9#bm5

Comment: Found my problem.  I was referencing the main UI instead of the report.  I've only ref the UI a 100x.


The FORMAT event is interesting.  It's not listed in the Report Properties in Design View.

Comment: FORMAT is not an event of report, it is event of sections. It is available when a section of the report is selected in design, such as the Detail section. FORMAT only executes in PrintPreview or direct to print. What 'user interaction'? Users cannot interact with report in PrintPreview.